# ARC with USB access?

Tags: android, usb, google-chrome-arc

I've got an Android application which can be remote controlled by USB midi devices. The app itself is running fine with google ARC but the USB module doesn't detect any USB device.
I already found that it is possible for Chrome apps to use usb but only when declaring each specific device in the manifest (https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_usb).

Does Google ARC support USB access?
Will it be possible to get a list with all USB devices without declaring them first in the manifest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, ARC does not currently implement a USB service that proxies to the Chrome USB interface.

Feel free to [file a bug](http://goo.gl/megdlG) however.

If we do implement it, is will likely have the same limit where you must predeclare the devices you want access to, for the same reason listed on the page you link to.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Do you think it would be possible to add a new permission which allows a chrome app to access all usb devices? Maybe with an extra warning for the user? I'm asking because there are thousands of different usb midi devices out there and it would be a real pain to list all of them in the manifest.

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure. It seems like there are good reasons to limit the list, but I can understand wanting to generically request access to "Any USB MIDI device", and perhaps that can be implemented.

Feel free to add that detail to the bug.

Answer (score 1):

Related note: a bug on UsbManager access within ARC was reported: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=475419

Comment: Apparently, the issue has restricted view - why?

Comment: Looks like only the author (in this case, me) is able to see it. This might explain it: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!searchin/chromium-discuss/restricted$20access/chromium-discuss/qy4nNh0NtR0/gDRzBv9ij0kJ

Comment: The link to google groups is dead/broken/restricted, but at least now there is another non-restricted issue open: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=480727