# Access to USB devices on Chromebook running Android APK

Tags: android, usb, google-chrome-arc

Problem description:

Android Run-time for Chrome allows you to run Android apps through chrome on a Chromebook, and I am using ARC Welder to prepair the APK's for this.
My application scans for USB devices connected, looking for one we'll use in app. The problem is that UsbManager's method `getDeviceList()` fails somewhere inside the method, returning `null` in error description. The list is not empty, it just fails. It doesn't matter if I have a device connected or not.

Question:

Is there a possible solution for this? Are there any known issues connected to Chromebook USB devices and Android method calls?

Comment: My guess is that this just isn't supported functionality yet.  ARC is rather new after all, and it may not yet be clear what the scope of its effort will be, though there seems to be interest in adding useful things.

Comment: Hm, then actually the question is if I can add to my Android app some native chrome arc module to access USB devices natively. Looks like a good way around the problem.

Comment: Does NaCL have access to usb ports/devices? if not then it might not be possible.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29509692/arc-with-usb-access

Comment: It's not answering the question, my app needs to use connected USB devices, not vise versa. That's why list of them won't help, because I need them to be discovered and operated. There is no actually prove link that it's impossible and no solution how to connect some native lib/code/etc to make it work.